# How would I join two arrays using zip but not returning tuples?

Tags: swift

So with two arrays:

1. `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
2. `[100, 200, 400, 800, 1600]`

How would I return:

`[1, 100, 2, 200, 3, 400, 4, 800]`

I know with `zip(firstArray, secondArray)` I can return `[(1,100), (2,200)]` etc...

But I'm not looking to work with tuples in this occasion. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using **Alladinian** intermediate map, since it's useless:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let b = [100, 200, 400, 800, 1600]

let c = zip(a, b).flatMap { [$0.0, $0.1] }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just map them to arrays & flatMap the result:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let b = [100, 200, 400, 800, 1600]

let c = zip(a, b).map { [$0.0, $0.1] }.flatMap { $0 }

print(c) // Gives [1, 100, 2, 200, 3, 400, 4, 800, 5, 1600]
```

or as pointed out in the comments by @Sweeper with a single flatMap:

```
let c = zip(a, b).flatMap { [$0.0, $0.1] }
```

Comment: @Sweeper Of course, you're right. Thanks.